# How to create static binary which runs on every distro?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, packaging

Some linux apps like supertuxkart or regnum online have static binaries, which after downloading just work without needing to install any shared library. On every distro. How can I make such an app?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ensure that all your resources are contained in the executable and link the executable statically:

```
gcc -o foo main.o -static -lbaz -lbar
```

However, this also has drawbacks. Look up dynamic linking.

Comment: If I link statically lib A, which itself links lib B, do I have to link lib B too?

Comment: @user1873947: When you link statically, libraries cannot refer to other libraries. You'll have to name them all on the command line, or use `libtool`.

Comment: okay. for binaries there is a linux command which says what shared libs it uses, is there something like that for libs? to check what I need to link.

Comment: @user1873947: No, because you can't know by design. A static library archive (`.a`) is a bunch of functions. `pkg-config` knows when the library author was nice enough to create a `.pc` file, otherwise you read the documentation and have fun.

Comment: last question, on windows there is mingw command line flag to link c++ library statically, is there something like that for g++?

Comment: @user1873947: `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`.